# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpRequest.touch(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/util/ReferenceCounted

Tags: java, netty

I'm new to the world of Java and trying to send a Https request. When I try to send a request through the channel I get the following error

`java.lang.AbstractMethodError:io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpRequest.touch(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/util/ReferenceCounted`

Here is my pipeline code

```
if (sslCtx != null) {
                         ch.pipeline().addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
                     }

                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpClientCodec());

                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpContentDecompressor());

                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
                     ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());
                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new ClientHandler());
```

Here is my bootstrap code

```
ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port).sync(); 

             ByteBuf bbuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

             FullHttpRequest request = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(
                     HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, uri,bbuf,Boolean.FALSE);
             request.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, host);
             request.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
             request.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, bbuf.readableBytes());
             ((DefaultFullHttpRequest) request).content().clear().writeBytes(bbuf);

             f.channel().writeAndFlush(request);
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpRequest.touch(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/util/ReferenceCounted;
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.touch(ReferenceCountUtil.java:73)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:107)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:821)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:805)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:842)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1032)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:296
```

Context: Trying to send an HTTPS request

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share more context? Stack trace, what you are trying to achieve, what have you tried..

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek have updated the post. context is I'm trying to send a https request from client to server. Not sure what else I can give for context

Comment: what is the version of netty you re using?

Comment: netty version 4.1.6

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you have multiple Netty 4.x dependency versions on your class path. Just ensure you only have the latest on the class path and it should work